# Issue with cursor position in IE11

Tags: onclick, internet-explorer-11, cursor-position

i'm working on click event on text field where i'm trying to get the systime. 
The main problem is in IE browser when i click on the text field the cursor pointer is moving to start of the text.

I tried to find the browser type and using Focus(), setSelectionRange() the cursor is positioned at the end of the text.

**I want the cursor to be positioned wherever i click in the text field rather than moving to either start or end and even if i click multiple times the cursor should be at the position i've clicked rather than moving to start of the text field in IE browsers**.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentdate = new Date();
  var datetime = currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes();
  //console.log(datetime);
  $("#test").val(datetime);
});

$("#test").click(function() {
  var currentdate = new Date();
  var datetime = currentdate.getHours() + ":" + currentdate.getMinutes();
  $("#test").val(datetime);

  /***IE browser code starts here ***/

  var ms_ie = false;
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var old_ie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
  var new_ie = ua.indexOf('Trident/');

  if ((old_ie > -1) || (new_ie > -1)) {
    ms_ie = true;
  }

  if (ms_ie) {

    var SearchInput = $('#test');
    //SearchInput.val(SearchInput.val() + ' World!');
    var strLength = SearchInput.val().length;
    SearchInput.focus();
    SearchInput[0].setSelectionRange(strLength, SearchInput.caret(position));
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="test" id="test" value="Hello" />
```